# wp_remote_post doesn't work with more than 1024 bytes in the body

Tags: wp-remote-post

## What I need

I'm working with a third-party API (for the intents of this question, it's irrelevant which one) and need to send a POST request to an external service.

I'm trying to use `wp_remote_post` to achieve what I need, but there seems to be a limit to the amount of data it can send in its request body.

## The issue I'm facing

It gets sent *only if the body contains **up to 1024 characters***. One character more and the request (apparently) isn't sent.

## Debug

I'm trying to debug the issue using [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) to listen for the POST requests at `$url`, and manually setting `$body` as a string of "bla bla bla (...)". They only show up when `$body` contains 1024 or less chars. **I don't get a 5xx error or any other error message. In fact, `is_wp_error( $response )` returns *false***.

However, if I use a tool such as [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com) to generate a similar POST request **outside WP** with more than 1024 characters in its body, ngrok receives it just fine.

---

- WP -> request body smaller than 1024 bytes -> ngrok = OK
- WP -> request body bigger than 1024 bytes -> ngrok = ??
- Postman -> request body smaller than 1024 bytes -> ngrok = OK
- Postman -> request body bigger than 1024 bytes -> ngrok = OK

## What I tried

- Sending the same request from outside WordPress with more than 1024 bytes on its body: it works.
- A brand new WordPress install with no plugins and a default theme (twentyseventeen): it doesn't work.
- Trying on a different PC, with the latest Fedora install, the latest Linux kernel, the latest Firefox version, the latest Docker version: didn't work.

## My setup

- Fedora Linux 24 kernel 4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64
- Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
- WordPress 4.9.5 from the [official Docker image for WordPress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)
- Firefox 54
- ngrok 2.2.8

All tests are being made on my local machine, with WordPress 4.9.5 running inside a Docker container with the default WordPress image, and it uses the unmodified default configuration, except for the following custom php ini lines:

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 600
```

## The code

```
  $response = wp_remote_post( $url,
    array(
      'timeout' => 60,
      'redirection' => 5,
      'blocking' => true,
      'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      ),
      'body' => 'bla bla (...)' // fails if larger than 1024
    )
  );

  if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
  } else { echo "Request sent"; }
```

Comment: I see you've specified a content type of JSON, but your payload is not valid JSON. If it doesn't return a `WP_Error` it'll return an `array`, have you inspected that array to see what the response is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you happen to be using the CURL transport, then it sometimes has minor problems sending POST requests greater than 1024 characters. More info here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463144/php-http-post-fails-when-curl-data-1024

The fix suggested there is to send an empty Expect: header. You can do this by modifying your code thusly:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url,
    array(
      'timeout' => 60,
      'redirection' => 5,
      'blocking' => true,
      'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Expect' => '',
      ),
      'body' => 'bla bla (...)' // fails if larger than 1024
    )
  );
```

Edit: more info:

Some versions of curl and PHP, when you put in more than 1024 characters in the body, will send the headers first and then an "Expect: 100-continue" header. A webserver receiving this then should respond with a 100 Continue status for the client to continue to send the rest of the body.

If you're using a real webserver, then it will send that response to receive the rest of the message. Some older webservers did not do this, thus the given workaround in that previous question.

I don't know what ngrok is, but I'm betting it is not responding like a normal webserver here. Without that server saying to continue the POST, curl waits for it to do so. It times out eventually.